# ViewData["s"].ToString() vs. Request.QueryString["s"].ToString(), what is returned if "s" was never set?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, query-string, viewdata

If in my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     //no code implied
     return View;
}
```

Then in the view that is returned:

```
<%if(ViewData["SomeString"].ToString() != "True") {%> show this <%}%>
```

I will get an error at runtime because of an object reference having no object.

However inside of a page where I do:

```
<%if(Request.QueryString["Something"].ToString() != "True") {%> show this <%}%>
```

Update: I actually do get the error.

Edit: Looks like they act the same after all.

Comment: Calling ToString on NameValueCollection item is duplication. Value is already string. In ViewDataCollection can be any object, why don't you write simply if(!(bool)ViewData["SomeString"]) ? Even better use strongly typed ViewData.Model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `ViewData` and `QueryString` will return `null` for non-existent key. When you're trying to call a method (in your case, `ToString`) on a `null` object reference, you get a `NullReferenceException`.

I'm not sure what's not clear in this situation.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense now. The NullReferenceException is caused by the ToString() call not the comparison (if ToString is excluded it will not error out when comparing to a string even if non-existent key is referenced).